# Calling a servlet programmatically when a specific criteria is met

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp, servlets

I am working on a JSP app and I have successfully created an HttpServlet that allows user to download a file on the browser. I have tested it by calling the servlet using and href tag and the file is downloaded as it should.

Now, I want instead of using href to call the servlet when some criteria is met. For example I have the following JAVA code:

```
if (criteria.isMet())  {
   
   String linkToCallServlet = "the servlet link";
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(linkToCallServlet).openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.getInputStream();

}
```

When I execute this code the servlet is executed as it should but the file is not downloaded on browser's window.

Also, no error appears. Any idea why? I have tested on Chrome and Edge

Comment: You're not even reading the stream in that code. Did you post the right code? If you're intending to open in a browser, you should probably be using `java.awt.Desktop` Also, it's *criterion*

Comment: thanks for the comment. I wanted to write "some criteria" and accidentally I wrote "a criteria".

The code is a mock. in ```linkToCallServlet``` is the actual link. it looks like that conn.getInputStream() calls successfully the servlet.

Comment: It doesn't matter (to my comments) what the link is.